# How to get jQuery animateNumber to pull value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, numbers

I am trying to implement [jQuery animateNumber](https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber), and I have it working like the demo just fine. However, I want to modify it so that it pulls the number from the HTML, rather than setting it in the script. I tried the following, but it just shows "NAN." What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="stat-title animate-number">$16,309</div>

    <script>
    $('.animate-number').each(function(){

        var value = new Number;

        // Grab contents of element and turn it into a number
        value = $(this).text();
        value = parseInt(value);

        // Set the starting text to 0
        $(this).text('0');


        $(this).animateNumber(
        {
            number: value,

        },
        1000
        )

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that ParseInt is choking on the dollar sign. Then when you remove that, it only reads up to comma and animates to 16.  Take them both out, and it works.

```
value = $(this).text().replace(/[\,\$]/g,'');
```

But, you'll need to include this option to get your comma back:

```
var comma_separator_number_step = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator(',')
$(this).animateNumber(
    {
        number: value,
        numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
    },
    1000
)
```

To get your dollar sign back, you could change your html to something like this:

```
<div>$<span class="stat-title animate-number">16,309</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ParseInt is failing because of the $ character. Also, the comma is messing with parseInt and giving you the value 16 instead of 16309. After that, the animation seems to be working. Also, you don't necessarily have to replace it with 0 since animateNumber automatically starts from 0. Here's my work so far on JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0m9828kn/1

```
$('.animate-number').each(function(){

    var value = $(this).text();
    value = value.substring(1, value.length);//Remove $ sign
    value = value.replace(/,/g, "");//Remove all commas
    value = parseInt(value);

    //$(this).text("0"); //This part isn't actually necessary

    $(this).animateNumber(
        {
            number: value
        },
        1000
    )
});
```